# Identifier not found FindFirstFile

Tags: c++, windows, win-universal-app

I'm trying to use this function FindFirstFile that is in the windows API and I've used it before but I can't find it anymore. It just tells me identifier not found. I have other variations of it FindFirstFileExW, FindFirstFileExA, and FindFirstFileEx but I don't have FindFirstFile. I can even include the specific header that it is supposed to be in FileAPI.h. I read on [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1401b946-9364-46e2-8dcd-c74a72ffcc1a/replace-in-c?forum=vcgeneral) with a similar problem that I should include stdafx.h before windows.h but I can't even find stdafx.h.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx

If you can't answer the question could one describe how to use FindFirstFileEx to do the same thing as FindFirstFile as FindFirstFileEx has been described on msdn as being FindFirstFile with more attributes too it.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? And what version? For example is it Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani vs2015 (v140)

Comment: This makes no sense. `FindFirstFile` and `FindFirstFileEx` are in the same header file.  `include "windows.h"` should be enough. You may or may not need `"stdafx.h"` If the VS2015 doesn't complain about it then you don't need it. Maybe the project settings are messed up. If you don't have a huge project then create a new Win32 project. Just incase it's IntelliSense that's complaining then you can ignore it.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani The problem occurs in my dx12 universal app project. What's so different from a universal app? I tried just an blank universal app and I could could only find the 3 again. I also tried a win32 console app and found it just fine. I now realize I should have specified it was a universal app.

Comment: Yes, I see the same thing. It's weird. Usage of Ex version is this: `FindFirstFileEx(L"c:\\test\\*", FindExInfoStandard, &findData, FindExSearchNameMatch, 0, 0); `

Comment: Perhaps FindFirstFile() is not supported on Universal Windows Platform apps. It's not supported on Windows Store apps, at least. I would imagine they want you to use FindFirstFileEx() anyway. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx) for information about UWP apps.

Comment: Please make up your mind which platform you are using. You tagged this with both `winapi` and `win-universal-app`, but they are different. `FindFirstFile` is a `winapi` function but not a `win-universal-app` function. For `win-universal-app`, you use [`StorageFolder.GetItemsAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getitemsasync.aspx).

Comment: @AndrewWilson - Just look it up in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419(v=vs.85).aspx) it tells you how to use `FindFileEx` and even includes an example which provides the same output as using `FindFile`. Kids these days have no idea how easy they've got it - once upon a time we had to spend hours poring over paper books in a library. Now you've got the net at your fingertips. (Rob Schneider voice) You can do it!

Answer (score 4):

[`FindFirstFile` is documented as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Minimum supported client: Windows XP [**desktop apps only**]

The API is not available to universal apps. The universal equivalent is [`StorageFolder.GetItemsAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getitemsasync.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

According to [APIs present on all Windows 10 devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt644399.aspx), `FindFirstFile` is present in Windows 10 from version `10.0.14393.0`, whereas `FindFirstFileEx` from version `10.0.10240.0`. [14393 is the Anniversary Update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history), and 10240 from "Threshold 1" a.k.a. RTM a.k.a. "Version 1507". So it's possible you have an older version of Windows API. I'm not sure why Microsoft would include one function but not the other, when both were available previously - maybe just an oversight?

So your simplest solution is to **upgrade to Windows 10 Anniversary Update or later**.

Failing that, it's also a very simple code change. According to [TFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/aa364419.aspx):

> The following call:
>
> ```
> FindFirstFileEx( lpFileName, 
>                  FindExInfoStandard, 
>                  lpFindData, 
>                  FindExSearchNameMatch, 
>                  NULL, 
>                  0 );
> ```
>
> Is equivalent to the following call:
>
> ```
> FindFirstFile( lpFileName, lpFindData );
> ```